# Spark - chained transformations lead to exception

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working with data that has the following schema

```
Array(Struct(field1, field2)) -> lets call it arr
```

Performing the following operation - chained `withColumn`:

```
df = df.withColumn("arr_exploded", df.col("arr")).withColumn("field1", df.col("arr_exploded.field1"))
```

Leads to a crash with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name "arr_exploded.field1" among (arr);
```

So that means the second `withColumn` is executing first. Why does this happen and how to prevent it?

Note, I found out that the following solutions work, which one is better?

```
/* Two Line approach */
df = df.withColumn("arr_exploded", df.col("arr"))
df = df.withColumn("field1", df.col("arr_exploded.field1"))
```

```
/* Checkpoint approach */
df = df.withColumn("arr_exploded", df.col("arr")).checkpoint().withColumn("field1", df.col("arr_exploded.field1"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DataFrame`s are immutable by nature, each method returns a new instance.
`withColumn` does the same.

When you use `df.col("arr_exploded.field1")` your `df` reference still points to the old instance.

The first approach is better, you could do it in one line:

```
import spark.implicits._
df.withColumn("arr_exploded", $"arr").withColumn("field1", $"arr_exploded")
```

Java way

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;
df.withColumn("arr_exploded", col("arr")).withColumn("field1", col("arr_exploded"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)
Sadly I'm using Java and implicits are out of reach.

Comment: @krystalgamer I have added Java example

Comment: Thank you so much! Been using `org.apache.spark.sql.functions` a lot, such a useful package!